# CSS Text-Indent or Blockquote

Tags: css, text-indent

If the CSS text-indent will only do the first line, is there anything "wrong" with using the blockquote with the attribute of `text-indent: xxx;` that way everything within the blockquote attribute will be indented? Or, maybe that is the "right way" and I just don't know it (new/learning HTML and CSS)

Comment: *...that way everything within the blockquote attribute will be indented?* - looks like you've even not tried it yet?

Comment: You haven't made it clear what you want to do. Why use indent if you're using blockquote? Anyhow, don't use HTML for presentation. You are probably looking for left margin or padding.

Answer (score 3):

The way to indent all lines of text in a block or, really, a block as a whole is to set `margin-left` or `padding-left` on it. The choice between these properties is relevant if the block has a left border (the border appears between margin and padding) or if it has a background color or background image (the background extends to the padding but not the margin).

Using the `blockquote` element means in practice setting a `40px` margin on the left *and* on the right *and* a `1em` margin above and blow. In the 1990s, and even later, `blockquote` was often used for indentation, because CSS was not available. It’s a blunt instrument, and using it is frowned upon as a matter of principle.

Answer (score 0):

The text-indent property allows you to indent the first line of text within an element. The amount you want the line indented by can be specified in a number of ways but is usually given in pixels or ems.
It can take a negative value, which means it can be used to push text off the browser window. You can see this technique used in this example, where the  element uses a background image to represent the heading. The text has been moved far to the left, off the screen. (Background images are covered on pages 413-418.)